# Nginx configuration

Tags: node.js, nginx, redirect

In the below code Im redirecting through nginx to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/app1/namelist/name=xyz`. When I hit `http://127.0.0.1:80/`, it throws an error "Cannot GET/". How can I resolve this problem?

If I directly hit `127.0.0.1:3000/app1/namelist/name=xyz`, it should redirect via nginx. Is it possible to configure in nginx?

```
#user  nobody; worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024; 
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;  
    upstream node_entry {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000; 
    }

    server {    
        listen       80;
        server_name  127.0.0.1;

        location / {
            #root   html;
            #index  index.html index.htm;
            #return 503;
            proxy_pass     http://node_entry/;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you said `/app1/namelist` while the upstream only says `127.0.0.1:3000`

Comment: Could you clarify: does :80/ need to hit :3000/app1/namelist/name=xyz? proxy passing will send the path to the upstream. / will still be / on port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as nginx is concerned, I would remove the trailing slash from your proxy pass line so it looks like this:

proxy_pass     http://node_entry;

If that doesn't work, the response must be coming from your upstream.